# Sketch the graph of the function $g(x) = \frac{2x^2 + 2x}{x^2 - 11x - 12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the function $$g(x)= \frac{2x^2+2x}{x^2-11x-12}$$
a) What is the domain of the function?
b) Sketch the complete graph.

I have factored $g(x)$ as $$\frac{2x}{x-12}$$ cancelling $x+1$ terms.
I got the domain to be $x \in \mathbb{R} - \{-1,12\}$. Is it right?
Also, while drawing the graph how does it go about the point $x=-1$? Should I just draw an open dot on $y$ at $x=-1$?

Comment: see here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(2*x%5E2%2B2x)%2F(x%5E2-11*x-12)+from+x%3D-100+to+100

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{2x}{x - 12}$?  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $\displaystyle \frac{2x^2+2x}{x^2-11x+12}=\frac{2x(x+1)}{(x+1)(x-12)}$

We can simplify this to $\displaystyle \frac{2x}{x-12}$.

Keep in mind that at $x=-1$, we will have a removable discontinuity, an open circle.

The numerator tells us that we have a zero at $x=0$.

Constructing a sign chart tells us

++++++ 0 ------- 12 +++++

Therefore, the graph PEACEFULLY goes from positive to negative at $x=0$.

Then, the graph has an asymptote, and approaches $-\infty$ from the left and then $+\infty$ from the right, at $x=12$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: note that $$\frac{2x^2+2x}{x^2-11x-12}=\frac{2x(x+1)}{(x-12)(x+1)}$$

Comment: its -12 edit your denominator, sir

Comment: Again, did you read the question? this was already noted by the OP.

Comment: @themaker  The OP originally wrote $g(x) = \frac{2x}{x - 11}$.

Comment: and this is only true if $$x\ne -1$$